# Is it possible to customize a belongs_to association of an ActiveAdmin resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models linked by a polymorphic `belongs_to` association:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, class_name: 'ImageAsset', as: :owner, inverse_of: :owner, dependent: :destroy
end

class ImageAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

I want to show the `ImageAsset` resource as an embedded resource of an `Item` in the admin (I don't care about the other possibilities of the polymorphic association).

I've been checking [ActiveAdmin repository](http://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) and [docs](http://activeadmin.info) and there doesn't seem to be a way to configure a `belongs_to` association, not even to change the association name (say a `User` model referenced as an `author`), am I right? What are the alternatives?

**Edit** Here are some things that I've been trying without luck in the `ActiveAdmin.register ImageAsset` block:

- `belongs_to :owner` then accesing `/admin/items/4/images` or `/admin/items/4/image_assets` throws `Could not find Owner in admin`
- `belongs_to :item` then accessing `/admin/items/4/images` throws a 404: `No route matches [GET] "/admin/items/4/images"`
- `belongs_to :item` then accessing `/admin/items/4/image_assets` throws `undefined method 'image_assets' for #<Item:0x0000000b2b65a0>`

Comment: Would it be okay to have the `ImageAsset` also belongs_to `Item` or do you purposely not want to ?

Comment: It is definitely possible to use an alias for the assocation name, and `ActiveAdmin` can handle most `belongs_to` assocations fine. You wil run into problems though with setting up the objects for the nested forms generated by formtastic. Could you post your `active_admin register blocks`, and the `form do ... end` declaration?

Comment: @rorofromfrance it's legacy code :( I don't care if I'm not able to manage the other associations through the admin, but this one is relevant.

Comment: @SjorsBranderhorst I just edited the question by adding some things I've tried already. I don't have a custom form for this resource yet. I wanted to get the association working and then build up from there. Do you think this is a bug in ActiveAdmin? Thanks!

Comment: I do not think it is a bug in ActiveAdmin. I suggest you search for _inverse_of_ on this page [http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to]. Polymorhic associations and :inverse_of do not play well together. What you could do first is remove the :inverse_of option. How exactly do you want to present the ImageAsset for an Item in the ActiveAdmin interface?